# Python Pandas memory management

Tags: python, pandas, memory, ram

2 questions :

1. When we delete/drop a dataframe and use gc.collect(), Does the python empty the ram occupied?
2. if we do df.to_csv(filename), will that df be referring to the file after that or the data still being referred from in-memory(RAM)?

Answer (score 0):

1. When we delete/drop a dataframe and use gc.collect(), Does the python empty the ram occupied?

> Yes, it will be empty space in the RAM.

2. If we do df.to_csv(filename), will that df be referring to the file after that or the data still being referred from in-memory(RAM)?

   No, it will be not refer from the file it will still refer to the df variable.